# Python dynamic dataframe name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm stuck on trying to use dynamic names for dataframe in Python.
My goal is to read a list of csv files in a folder like:

```
aaa.csv

bbb.csv

ccc.csv
```

for example with:

```
path = "../somepath/"
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path)]
```

Then, loop on the list and for every step create a dataframe from a csv file, something like

```
df_aaa = pd.read_csv('/../csv/aaa.csv')
```

I am trying to create a function to read the files in a folder and create the dataframes, to be invoked and reused by other python scripts, instead of manually creating the dataframes in every script.

Is it possible? I'm trying to use a dictionary but I cannot figure out the solution.

Thank you

Comment: list of dictionary, for example you can create dictionary {"file_name": DataFrame} and then append this dictionary to a list. So at the end you have result as [{"aaa.csv": df},{"bbb.csv": df},] . If your file_name are not unique then need to find way to create key.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is an overwhelming need to create a mess of variable names, I would just use a dictionary, where you can dynamically create the key names and associate a value to each.

Something along the lines of:

```py
my_dataframes = dict()

for file in files:
    # Get the file name without the .csv extension
    file_name = os.path.basename(file).replace(".csv", "")
    my_dataframes[file_name] = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Comment: Hi, should be my_dataframes[file] = pd.read_csv(file) or my_dataframes[file_name] = pd.read_csv(file_name)?

Comment: It should be my_dataframe[file_name] = pd.read_csv(file). Edited response to fix typo. file is the full path to your csv ('/../csv/aaa.csv'), whereas file_name contains the name of the folder without the extension ('aaa').

Comment: Hi. I figured out... in order to save the correct df name and read the csv from path... I implemented the code, but it exit with error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'aaa.csv' on this line: my_dataframes[file_name] = pd.read_csv(file) It really find the file, because it tells "aaa.csv" the real file name

Comment: It seems it was an error with path... pd.read_csv(file with full path)

Comment: Now the last thing I am not able to do, is to print the dataframe content because if I do: print(my_dataframes[file_name]), it just print the last df in the for loop. But how can I choose a particular dataframe to print?

Comment: You'd have to do my_dataframes[xyz] if you want to access the contents of xyz.csv. You can see all available options by running print(list(my_dataframes.keys()))

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

credits to this cool video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMOA1pPVUc4

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "./path"

files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if not file.startswith('.')] # Ignore hidden files

#Define the next table as Pandas Dataframe
all_months_data = pd.DataFrame()

#loop to check each file by file name e append to the previous

for file in files:
    current_data = pd.read_csv(path+"/"+file)
    all_months_data = pd.concat([all_months_data, current_data])
#create a CSV DF with all data
all_months_data.to_csv("all_data_copy.csv", index=False)
```

Best Regards,

Tanai